# PostgreSQL insert into multiple tables, using foreign key from first insertion in the second insertion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to take an existing table and create two. I have a `sections` table that has a `file_url`, and now I need to move that into `url` field on `media_files` table. Also, I want to populate `attachments` table that acts as a `has_many :through` (in Rails) which means it keeps track of the foreign key relationships of `media_file_id` and `section_id`.

The closest that I've gotten is this:

```
WITH ids AS (
    INSERT INTO media_files (url, mimetype)
    SELECT file_url, 'image/jpeg'
    FROM sections
    WHERE file_url IS NOT NULL
    RETURNING id AS media_file_id, sections.id AS section_id
)
INSERT INTO attachments (media_file_id, section_id)
SELECT media_file_id, section_id
FROM ids
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sections"
LINE 6:         RETURNING id AS media_file_id, sections.id AS sectio...
```

which makes sense, but I'm not sure how to grab the `section_id`.

Is there a way to get this working? Maybe there's a better, alternative method?

**Edit:** Here's a link to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6fcaf/3)

Comment: An sqlfiddle would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid problems with duplicates you should use a `DISTINCT` clause in the first `INSERT`. This will make two sections point to the same media_file but it should be more than okay. (Upgraded from @a_horse_with_no_name answer)

```
WITH ids AS (
    INSERT INTO media_files (url, mimetype)
    SELECT DISTINCT file_url, 'image/jpeg'
    FROM sections
    WHERE file_url IS NOT NULL
    RETURNING id AS media_file_id, url AS file_url
)
INSERT INTO attachments (media_file_id, section_id)
SELECT ids.media_file_id, s.id
FROM ids
  JOIN sections s ON s.file_url = ids.file_url;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e9c8/2)

Comment: In, this case `DISTINCT` would make me lose the relation of `sections` that have matching `file_url`s. I still want to generate an `attachments` row in that case, using the existing `media_files` id.

Comment: @gylaz It won't, the sections that link to the same file (2,3) point to the same media_file as seen in the fiddle. So it works exactly as you describe it.

Answer (score 3):

I can only think of using an additional join in the outer insert:

```
WITH ids AS (
    INSERT INTO media_files (url, mimetype)
    SELECT file_url, 'image/jpeg'
    FROM sections
    WHERE file_url IS NOT NULL
    RETURNING id AS media_file_id, url AS file_url
)
INSERT INTO attachments (media_file_id, section_id)
SELECT ids.media_file_id, s.id
FROM ids
  JOIN sections s ON s.file_url = ids.file_url;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6fcaf/4

Comment: @JakubKania: yes, I was thinking about that. But the dupes would already be present in the original insert inot the `media_files` table and apparently that wasn't a problem (or gylaz didn't think about it)

Comment: Ideally, if there is a duplicate `file_url` in `sections` -- I would want to create a `media_files` row the first time, and the second time I encounter it, fetch the existing row from `media_files`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, if we'd want one section - one media file and avoid the dupes we could join the tables on row number.